# ubuntu 14.04 will not boot after installing alongside windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

Initially, after the installation, i was only able to boot into windows 7 as normal.
I installed Easybcd and put in the relevant info etc but it still will not boot into
ubuntu... i have tried all sorts of things but cannot figure out how to solve this problem.
Any help would be appreciated. Obviously i am not a very techy person so simple answers would be
much appreciated. I used the installation type... install U alongside Windows 7...
it worked fine on another pc but not the current one. Asus ux32vd...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

The best idea will be to use a boot repair disk, just download iso and burn it into USB drive, and it will do all the hard stuff itself for you :)

more details at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

EDIT: if you need direct steps:

1. Download http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/
2. burn it into USB using Universal USB installer (google it, i cant post the link due to priviledge issues)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question, this is much appreciated. I was a little late replying as I needed to find a reliable internet connection before using the Boot Repair tool. However, i have encountered a problem and now passed the URL for this onto Boot Repair. It is quite likely that I will contact you again if they are unable to offer a workable solution to my problem. Thank you for your patience...